# Why data.table CJ doesn't respect column major order

Tags: r, data.table

This is a curiosity more than a question, but I was wondering why `data.table` `CJ` function  returns an object with the rightmost index running faster (as opposite as base `expand.grid` function).

An example:

```
CJ(a=letters[1:2],b=LETTERS[1:2])
#   a b
#1: a A
#2: a B
#3: b A
#4: b B
expand.grid(a=letters[1:2],b=LETTERS[1:2])
#  a b
#1 a A
#2 b A
#3 a B
#4 b B
```

I think that the leftmost index running faster is more R-ish. Is there a reason for `CJ` to follow the other order?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I know that `data.table` make use of the [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) algorithm for at least some tasks (so possibly all sorting tasks), and this "running from right to left" behavior is a key characteristic of LSD radix sort.

Comment: @nrussell the result of `CJ` being sorted like that has nothing to do with radix sort. If you look at the source code - `CJ` is agnostic to what sort function you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's convenient to have the result of `CJ` sorted like that, as it can then be keyed by all of the columns, which it is, which then enables operations like this:

```
dt = data.table(a = c(1,2,1), b = 1:3, c = c('a', 'a', 'b'))
setkey(dt, a, c)
#   a b c
#1: 1 1 a
#2: 1 3 b
#3: 2 2 a

dt[CJ(unique(a), unique(c))]
#   a  b c
#1: 1  1 a
#2: 1  3 b
#3: 2  2 a
#4: 2 NA b

# just checking the key:
key(dt[, CJ(unique(a), unique(c))])
#[1] "V1" "V2"
```

Comment: I see your point, although I don't think it's THE reason. In `x[i]` data.table grammar, it's necessary that just `x` is keyed; it seems to me that you could obtain the same result if in the call to `CJ` you set `sorted=FALSE`.

Comment: @nicola you're right. I thought the key would be necessary for some joins, but I can't think of such a scenario.

Comment: @nicola if one is going to sort it, it still only makes sense to sort it this way, because you can then set a key. The other sorting order is useless in the `data.table` world.

Comment: yes, but in this case the questions become: why `CJ` sets keys by default, why in left-order and why you cannot obtain the right-order in an obvious way?

Comment: @nicola - I think I answered the "why in left-order" part. Why it sets keys by default - I'm not so certain anymore - maybe Matt can clarify - could be for historical reasons (wild guess - maybe joins only worked if data was keyed in the beginning). To obtain the right-order, just sort yourself: `dt = CJ(letters, LETTERS); setkeyv(dt, rev(names(dt)))`

Comment: I agree that historical reasons could play a big role in the issue. I think I'm going to wait a little more to see if something new comes out and then I'll accept your answer. Thank you.